# Error retrieving LinkedIn user's profile using ASP.NET MVC and OAuthWebSecurity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oauth, linkedin-api

I am having a hard time with LinkedIn API and I am sure I am doing something wrong but I can't figure out what. I have an ASP.NET MVC 4 app and inside AuthConfig.cs I have:

OAuthWebSecurity.RegisterLinkedInClient("apikey", "secretkey");

Using the default AccountController I am able to authenticate against LinkedIn API. Inside ExternalLoginCallback method, I am storing the accessToken in session variable. However, after that I can't use this accessToken to get information about the user's profile. I am always getting a 401 (invalid access token). This is what I have in one of my test methods:

(HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(string.Format("https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~?oauth2_access_token={0}", accessToken)

Could anyone point out what I am missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the current MVC implementation uses oauth1 and the OAuth1 accessToken will not work for oath2 requests. It is very complicated and I struggle with it myself. You will have to write your own provider. See https://coderwall.com/p/rznlfg. But I need an OAuth2Client integrated implementation for MVC4. Can anybody help, please?

Comment: You're right. After more investigation I ended up figuring that out, but thanks! I implemented my own LinkedInClient and it wasn't a difficult task. Basically, all I did was to create a new class inheriting from OAuth2Client and then I overwrote the VerifyAuthentication, GetServiceLoginUrl, GetUserData and QueryAccessToken methods.

You can get some ideas from FacebookClient (http://bit.ly/1oyrKoL)

Comment: BTW, this might help:

On GetUserData, use something like https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,last-name,headline,public-profile-url)?oauth2_access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>.

On GetServiceLoginUrl, use https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization as the base url and append the following querystring parameters: response_type (always "code"), client_id, scope, state and redirect_uri.

On QueryAccessToken, use https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken and pass these parameters: grant_type (always "authorization_code"), code, client_id, client_secret and rediret_uri.